# Uninitialized Merge replication subscription

Tags: sql-server-2012, merge-replication

I have 3 separate SQL Server 2012 databases running on 3 VM's. I have successfully configured one pull subscription to the distributor but when I add a 2nd subscription on another SQL Server the subscription never initializes. The new subscription is configured exactly the same as the working subscription.

Both subscriptions are set to impersonate the service account.
Is there a way to see exactly what the failure is?

Comment: Open up the Replication Monitor and take a look at the agents.  You should be able to see the errors that correspond to your issue.

Comment: Replication Monitor does not show any detail on the subscription with uninitialized status. When I attempt to see the errors the message is "Replication Monitor could not open the Detail Window"